# SwiftCharts want create a UIButton in InfoBubble

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swiftcharts

In my app, I use `SwiftCharts` lib to create some charts, like that :

[image: demo picture]

You can see in the picture , I create a `BubbleInfo` view when user tap the point in the chart, then I add a `UIButton` in `BubbleInfo` view, code in below:

```
    bubbleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 100))

    let infoView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: w, height: h - 30))
    infoView.textColor = UIColor.white
    infoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    infoView.text = "Some text about \(chartPoint)"
    infoView.font = ExamplesDefaults.fontWithSize(Env.iPad ? 14 : 12)
    infoView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    //create button            
    let btn = UIButton(frame: infoView.bounds)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    btn.addTarget(weakSelf, action: #selector(weakSelf.btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    bubbleView.addSubview(infoView)
    bubbleView.addSubview(btn)
```

But when I tap the button, nothing happened!

What wrong with it?
How could I fix it?
thanks ;)

Comment: Is this still unsolved?

Comment: I figure out it :) I use event to sim this function.